# How can I create a URI from an xml data?

Tags: html, xml, uri

I'm trying to create a simple right-click to a html link and then 'save as' and saving the xml data... the url looks something like this:

```
http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/services/v2/spls/1a665e64-9f30-be37-4a83-38789f1f1e89.xml
```

Note: For some reason the browser does not display the xml I can only view it on the source (I know most modern browsers display the xml tags)

I tried something like this:

```
var uri = "data:application/xml;charset=UTF-8," + encodeURIComponent(xmldata);
```

But this has not worked out..
I have searched on this topic but had no success.
Any help? thanks

Comment: Isn’t this default browser behaviour? Right click → "Save target as …"

Comment: It's not.. only gives me the option to save link as. the 'a' element href value needs to be an uri so I can save the file directly. I was able to do so with json but not xml...

Comment: But the link target *is* the XML file, no? So if you save the link (via right-click), you have saved the file `1a665e64-9f30-be37-4a83-38789f1f1e89.xml`, or what happens else?